# Magnetometer raw data to azimuth and altitude in stellarium

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, embedded, magnetometer, stellarium

I've got raspberry Pi 3B+ and LSM303DHLC magnetometer + accelerometer module. I downloaded sample app in python to get data from it. I'm trying to calculate position of my telescope using this and put it into Stellarium or other sky database app.
I found that I can calculate it using `atan2` function: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/18625/converting-three-axis-magnetometer-to-degrees 
Here are my results (from MS Excell spreadsheet):

```
rules:              
az = atan2(x, y) * 180 / M_PI;              
heading = atan2(y, x) * 180 / M_PI;             

Magnetometer raw data    calculation    
X   Y                     az    alt
-11,73  28,18       112,5930088 -22,59300884
-11,55  28,09       112,3419626 -22,34196264
-11,46  28,27       112,0556682 -22,05566819
-11,55  28,00       112,4074033 -22,40740332
30,55   11,64       20,85414603 69,14585397
31,18   1,27        2,337792538 87,66220746
35,18   -10,18      -16,14093801    106,140938
29,18   -29,00      -44,82077278    134,8207728
24,73   -22,36      -42,12733936    132,1273394
0,18    -16,64      -89,37320174    179,3732017
-0,18   -4,82       -92,16332007    -177,8366799
39,46   -12,27      -17,2789974 107,2789974
4,46    -13,82      -72,13039013    162,1303901
-21,36  -13,00      -148,6794756    -121,3205244
16,46   -28,36      -59,88040243    149,8804024
22,55   -3,46       -8,712739171    98,71273917
23,82   7,09        16,57911127 73,42088873
18,00   -19,64      -47,4890244 137,4890244
9,00    -9,82       -47,4890244 137,4890244
-1,64   3,09        117,891309  -27,89130902
-11,64  7,46        147,3529597 -57,35295972
-18,55  13,55       143,8561477 -53,85614771
-17,91  14,73       140,5687197 -50,56871969
10,73   32,73       71,85229576 18,14770424
15,00   -9,73       -32,96206433    122,9620643
3,00    29,70       84,2321111  5,767888898
```

But when I put them into Stellarium search window (horizontal coordinates system):
 [image: Stellarium]

I realized that calculated data are incorerect ( don't show right position).

Two questions: what I'm doing wrong? And How can I put these data into stellarium programatically to show position mark?

Thank you for answers in advance